# Is it okay to use the FREE SSL Certificate offered by: Instant SSL by comodo? or Is StartCom better?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority

Is it okay to use the *FREE SSL Certificate* offered by: [Instant SSL by comodo](http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/free-ssl-certificate.html).

The site says:

> Our promise to you:
>
> There is absolutely no cost or commitment for your SSL certificate.
>
> You'll get free SSL with full https functionality and the golden padlock free
>   for 90 days

I want to use it for testing purposes.

> - Is it okay to use one?
> - Is there any catch?
> - Can I shift to other certificate provider later?
> - How good are the certificate offered by [StartCom](http://cert.startcom.org/)? Sine they are free, are there any catches?

Comment: If it's for testing purposes, why not just use a self-signed one?

Comment: @ceejayoz oh din't know I could do that! Lookin into it.

Comment: @ceejayoz since I want to test the site with some friends. Receiving an `untrusted` is not good :(. So, I better look for StartCom I guess.

Comment: You can't tell your friends to ignore the warning during testing?

Comment: @ceejayoz I can. But, I want more people to test it. So if I enable my friends to invite their friends, It will be a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm using StartCom without any problems: no browser warnings about invalid certs and so on.

Their schtick is to set the expiry of the certificate to a year, so you will need to go back to them every year to get a new one.  They will do some upsell to get you to buy something.

You can shift to a different provider later.  Just install the new cert in place of the old one.

Comment: +1 Also use them. The upsell attempts are minimal and they're straight forward with what's offered, no gimmicks. I'm quite happy so far.

Comment: That's quite true: they are most definitely not GoDaddy, where it takes 10 minutes to figure out how to get off a page without buying something you don't want.

Comment: StartCom is actually StartSSL. Any chance to make the edit?